# I must create app for localization of wearable device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

I'm a student of Politecnico di Torino and I must create an app for a personal project (IOS and Android mobile devices) for localization of wearable device in which there is GPS. I think to create an multiplatform app using html5 and javascript.
Can you help me? I don't know where to start!!!
On Internet I found codes for the GPS localization but these localization the device on which it is activated the app and not another device.

p.s. I'm sorry for my English :D

Comment: provide your code..

Comment: as long as you know a bit of js - best to start reading this (there are plenty of frameworks but i think these are the most common ones):  
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/ & https://cordova.apache.org & https://ionicframework.com

Comment: I need some advice to start. What can I do first?

Comment: first of all decide for [native/web/hybrid app](https://www.mobiloud.com/blog/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/) and search for examples, doku ;)

Comment: @MarcelD I think to do a hybrid app

Comment: k, so depending on your experience (HTML, CSS, JS, React etc...) decide for a framework and go go go ;)

Comment: _"I don't know where to start!!!"_ Start from reading about wearable devices with GPS, how the data is supposed to be read from them and whether it's even possible from a WebView with HTML5 and Javascript or whether it will require more "native" code as in Java for Android and Objective-C/Swift for iOS. If the idea seems impossible or too difficult, then pick something else. And also learn about what kind of questions belong to Stack Overflow and which don't. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to start making the base of the application and then start asking for the GPS, it's easy, if you search for it you will have the code instantly. But first do the base code, you can't start a house from the ceiling, I recommend that you use C# or Java, but you can also do it with JavaScript that has a bigger community.

Comment: except the recommendation to use C# or java - totally agree if she doesn't even know where to start - i think learning c# or java is a bit too much for a personal project, imo ;)

Comment: Well, the easiest language for learning is phyton but Java is more complete than it, so it's harder but if I learned on Java I think she can do it as well. And it's not a hard application she wants to do, like calling the GPS sensor.

Comment: iOS application from java code afaik is not really recommended by anybody...  correct me if im wrong ;)

Comment: not for iOS, didn't read it was for it, I just remembered Android :)